# Angular4 how to chain forkJoin with flatMap

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, chaining

I'm in the situation where I need to make 5 http calls that can be executed in parallel + another http call that need to be executed after these five.

I used forkJoin for the first 5, but I don't have any idea how to chain flatMap (or other function).

```
forkJoin(
      firstObservable,
      secondObservable,
      thirdObservable,
      ..)
      .subscribe(results => {

        this.myComposedObject = results[0];
        let secondResult = results[1];
        let thirdResult = results[2];
        [...]


        // !!! AT THIS POINT I WOULD NEED TO MAKE AN EXTRA CALL!
        // results[1] contains data I need to make the extra call


        // 
        this.myComposedObject.second = secondResult;
        this.myComposedObject.third = thirdResult;
});
```

I do this operation within a component, so at the end I assign data to myComposedObject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you said to make 5 parallel requests you can use `forkJoin`. Then you want to make another request when the previous 5 complete so you'll chain it with the `concatMap` operator (or `mergeMap` would work here as well).

Then you need to work with all the results combined so you can use `map` to add the last result to the the same array as the previous five.

```
forkJoin(
    firstObservable,
    secondObservable,
    thirdObservable,
    ...
  )
  .concatMap(firstFiveResults => makeAnotherCall(firstFiveResults[1])
    .map(anotherResult => [...firstFiveResults, anotherResult])
  )
  .subscribe(allResults => {
    this.myComposedObject.second = allResults[1];
    this.myComposedObject.third = allResults[2];
    // allResults[5] - response from `makeAnotherCall`
    ....
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that pointed me to the right direction.
I had some problem with results types. When I tried to assign

```
this.myComposedObject.second = allResults[1];
```

compiler complains about type conversion, so I'll report my solution here for other people.

In order to get rid of this problem you take advantage of "destructuring" (more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
forkJoin(
    firstObservable,
    secondObservable,
    thirdObservable,
    ...
  )
  .concatMap(firstFiveResults => makeAnotherCall(firstFiveResults[1])
    .map(anotherResult => [...firstFiveResults, anotherResult])
  )
  .subscribe((allResults: [
     TypeA, <-- type returned from firstObservable
     TypeB, 
     TypeC, 
     TypeD, 
     TypeE
   ]) => {
    this.myComposedObject.second = allResults[1];
    this.myComposedObject.third = allResults[2];
    // allResults[5] - response from `makeAnotherCall`
    ....
  });
```